# Does the function det() in matlab use parallel computing

Tags: matlab, matrix, parallel-processing, determinants

I have this very nasty matrix that has in it long polynomials that came from a solution of a resultant of two polynomials in two variables . I need to get the determinant of this matrix, should I try to find an algorithm to use parallel computing or does matlab do it anyway?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It does. It supports multithreaded computation, [according to Mathworks](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/95958).

Answer (score 1):

I have tried using `det` but have in fact been unable to find a matrix for which it took more than a fraction of a second to run.

Hence I don't think you should worry about parallelization here.

That being said: here is how you can determine whether it is parallelized in general:

1. Start the task/resource manager
2. Run the command of interest
3. See how many cores are being used

Comment: @user1 It depends on your OS, but that should be easy to find online. In oldfashioned windows I suspect it to be something like rightclick starbar, task manager, performance. This gives me one graph per core.

Answer (score 0):

Further to Luis' answer - `det` is not implemented for distributed arrays - but it is implemented for `gpuArray` if you have Parallel Computing Toolbox and a compatible GPU. Full list of `gpuArray` functions here: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/distcomp/run-built-in-functions-on-a-gpu.html